# Password recovery in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, password-recovery

Hi when I try to reset password I get this error:

> ArgumentError in PasswordResetsController#create
>
> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>
> app/models/user.rb:48:in `create_remember_token
>   app/models/user.rb:40:in`send_password_reset
>   app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:7:in `create'

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password &crarr; 
        reset has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
    else
      render :edit
    end
end
end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :create



  def send_password_reset
    create_remember_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Have anybody an Idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution in [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password)

added to before_save remember_token and changed create_remember_token

I don't know it's right? but it works

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { create_remember_token(:remember_token) }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :create

  def send_password_reset
    create_remember_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end



    def create_remember_token(column)
     begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
     end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling create_remember_token(:password_reset_token) when the method definition of create_remember_token accepts no paramaters.

In other words change

```
create_remember_token(:password_reset_token)
```

to

```
create_remember_token
```

in your send_password_reset method

Comment: Now I have template error because `crete_remember_token` is private method   password_reset.text.erb `<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.create_remember_token) %>`

Comment: Why not make it a public method?

Comment: ok, I made it public and now I have `undefined method `find_by_create_remember_token!' for #<Class:0x007fca97926210>`